# LINQ to entity Error: "Unable to create a null constant value of type ''System.Int32[]". Only entity types, enumeration types

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I am receiving the error listed when executing a linq query on my RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local entity. I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong or a solution.

> Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Int32[]'. Only
>   entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in
>   this context.

My LINQ query on my code first entity context:

```
var subjLocal = customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local.Where(s => 
    (s.fkRosterSetID == 0) &&
    (statsInfo.TestInstanceIDsList.Contains(s.fkTestInstanceID)) &&
    (s.fkTestTypeID == statsInfo.TestTypeID) &&
    (statsInfo.SchoolYearIDsList.Contains(s.fkSchoolYearID)) &&
    (s.fkRosterTypeID == 1) &&
    (s.fkSchoolID == 0) &&
    (s.fkDepartmentID == 1) &&
    (s.fkCourseID == 1) &&
    (s.fkPeriodID == 1) &&
    (statsInfo.DemoCatIDsList.Contains(s.fkDemoCommonCategoryID)) &&
    (statsInfo.DemoCodeIDsList.Contains(s.fkDemoCommonCodeID)) &&
    (statsInfo.TestSubjectIDsList.Contains(s.fkTest_SubjectID)));
```

Comment: Are you sure all your lists are non-null?  (i.e.  `TestInstanceIDsList`)

Comment: @KirkWoll oh man this is awkward. Thanks for that spot. One of the lists were null and I thought they were passed properly. Solved the issue, thanks

Comment: EF error messages usually leave much to be desired. :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like one of your `Int32[]` types is `null`. Try adding a check for that before accessing the `.Contains` methods:

```
var subjLocal = customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local.Where(s => 
    (s.fkRosterSetID == 0) &&
    (statsInfo.TestInstanceIDsList != null &&
        statsInfo.TestInstanceIDsList.Contains(s.fkTestInstanceID)) &&
    (s.fkTestTypeID == statsInfo.TestTypeID) &&
    (statsInfo.SchoolYearIDsList != null &&
        statsInfo.SchoolYearIDsList.Contains(s.fkSchoolYearID)) &&
    (s.fkRosterTypeID == 1) &&
    (s.fkSchoolID == 0) &&
    (s.fkDepartmentID == 1) &&
    (s.fkCourseID == 1) &&
    (s.fkPeriodID == 1) &&
    (statsInfo.DemoCatIDsList != null &&
        statsInfo.DemoCatIDsList.Contains(s.fkDemoCommonCategoryID)) &&
    (statsInfo.DemoCodeIDsList != null &&
        statsInfo.DemoCodeIDsList.Contains(s.fkDemoCommonCodeID)) &&
    (statsInfo.TestSubjectIDsList != null &&
        statsInfo.TestSubjectIDsList.Contains(s.fkTest_SubjectID)));
```

Alternatively, if it is Ok for them to be null (I assume it isn't, but just in case), you can change the above checks to follow this pattern:

```
(statsInfo.DemoCatIDsList == null ||
    statsInfo.DemoCatIDsList.Contains(s.fkDemoCommonCategoryID)) &&
```